# Why is my function not working when called from a vue.js component-generated element?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Why doesn't a function being called from an element generated by a vue.js component work?

I'm calling the exact same function from a normal element and from element created by a component in vue.js. The function only works in the first case and in the second case I get an error Uncaught TypeError: toggleCheckboxes is not a function.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hfrcj8pL/

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>Checkboxes</h1>
  <p>Please check the checkboxes below</p>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="5" name="item[0]" v-model="itens"> 5
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="10" name="item[1]" v-model="itens"> 10
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="16" name="item[3]" v-model="itens"> 16
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="18" name="item[4]" v-model="itens"> 18
  </label>
  <hr>
  <button type="button" @click="toggleCheckboxes()">Select All</button>

  <toggle></toggle>
</div>
```

Vue.js Part:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app', 
    data: {
        itens: [], 
    },
    methods: {
        toggleCheckboxes() {
            var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
            checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
                checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
            });
        }
    },
    components: {
        'toggle': {
            template: `
                <div>
                    <button type="button" @click="toggleCheckboxes()">Select All (component)</button>
                </div>
            `
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It works when this is done:

```
<toggle @tog="toggleCheckboxes"></toggle>
```

and in the Vue.js Part

```
<button type="button" @click="$emit('tog')">Select All (component)</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that you are inside a component, in your case the toggle component.

So, your html is inside, and inside toggle you have nothing, no function define.
Like you said, you need to say to the parent *"hey, my button is clicked"*, the way to do this is to use the `$emit`.

On the button click you can add

```
<button type="button" @click="$emit('selectAll')">Select All (component)</button>
```

Now, the child say to the parent *"selectAll"*, you need to execute the function you want in the parent component:

```
<toggle @selectAll="toggleCheckboxes"></toggle>
```